# Hip deformation with heel IK bone

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to learn how to implement IK bones in my rig. I followed a quick YouTube tutorial. However, when I move the IK heel bone, the mesh deforms badly at the hip area. Is this because I haven't added IK bones elsewhere (the tutorial only covered the heel)?

Here's how it looks.

[image]

Can anyone offer some guidance? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the IK constraint, and is a weight painting problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I think it might be because I removed the pelvis bones before doing the tutorial. I wanted to copy the rig from the tutorial, so I got rid of those bones. That'll be why the upper leg is the only thing influencing the pelvis, I assume?

Comment: … Yes, that sounds right. I’m not entirely sure, but it sounds plausible.